# Unable to click delete button, multiple view

Tags: automation, ui-automation, android-espresso, android-espresso-recorder

Unabel to click on delete button, getting error:

```
android.support.test.espresso.AmbiguousViewMatcherException: '(with id: cit:id/delete_button and has parent matching: with id: cit:id/count_and_delete and is displayed on the screen to the user)' matches multiple views in the hierarchy.
```

I am using following code to click on delete icon:

```
ViewInteraction appCompatImageView222 = onView(
                allOf(withId(R.id.delete_button),
                        withParent(withId(R.id.count_and_delete)),
                        isDisplayed()));
        appCompatImageView222.perform(actionOnItemAtPosition(0, click()));


ViewInteraction appCompatImageView222 = onView(
                    allOf(withId(R.id.delete_button),
                            withParent(withId(R.id.count_and_delete)),
                            isDisplayed()));
            appCompatImageView222.perform(click());
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your matcher `allOf(withId(R.id.delete_button), withParent(withId(R.id.count_and_delete)), isDisplayed()))` is still not unique enough, because it still finds two view matchers on your screen. Instead, try to match with the text in its grand-parent view:

```
onView(allOf(
        withId(R.id.delete_button),
        withParent(withParent(withChild(withText("Count 1"))))))
                .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
                .perform(click())
```